# Conditions in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a weird problem: my conditions are not working in javascript :/

this is my code:

```
var myposition = $("#audioWelcome").data("myposition");

/* condition */
if (myposition == "true") {
....
}
```

it's incorrect ? see my example : http://jsfiddle.net/qqK5J/2/ conditions are not working and html(); or data(); doesn't work too.

what is incorrect ?

Comment: Did you add attr `data-myposition="true"` in selector element?

Comment: yes, i did it, see the fiddle

Comment: Alternatively, use DOM `getAttribute()` instead of jQuery `data()`, which won't try to be clever and convert your value to not be a string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your question:

```
if (myposition == "true") {
```

doesn't work as expected because `myposition` is the **boolean** value `true`, which is not equal to the **string** value `"true"`.

You might wonder why `myposition` is a boolean value. That's because jQuery [converts it to a boolean](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5):

> Every attempt is made to convert the string to a JavaScript value (this includes booleans, numbers, objects, arrays, and null).

So all you really have to do is change your code to set booleans instead of strings and adjust the condition accordingly:

```
if (myposition) {
    $(this).html("afficher le lecteur");
    $('#audioWelcome').data('myposition', false);
} else {
    $(this).html("cacher le lecteur");
    $('#audioWelcome').data('myposition', true);

}
```

or shorter:

```
$(this).html(myposition ? "afficher le lecteur" : "cacher le lecteur");
$('#audioWelcome').data('myposition', !myposition);
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/qqK5J/11/)

Comment: Any reason why this(fiddle) won't work on a mobile device. I couldn't get this working on my tablet with chrome

Answer (score 1):

Removed the double quotes:

```
if (myposition == true) {
```

Updated JSFilddle at:

http://jsfiddle.net/qqK5J/5/

Updated:

```
    if (myposition == true) {

        $(this).html("afficher le lecteur");
        $('#audioWelcome').data('myposition', false);


    } else {

        $(this).html("cacher le lecteur");
        $('#audioWelcome').data('myposition', true);

    };
```

Updated fiddle at:

http://jsfiddle.net/qqK5J/10/

Comment: This only works the first time, not a working fiddle.

Comment: What do you mean? It toggles.

Comment: But after you toggle a few times, it gets stuck on "cacher le lecteur".

Comment: That's because `true != 'true'` to make this work, you also have to change the values you set booleans, not strings.

Comment: I see. I wasn't paying attention to the french words in the string, which seemingly look the same at a glance by the english speaking folks :)

Answer (score 1):

Great question!

It seems like javascript is confusing the "true" and "false" values when set as an attribute,

@Kyo suggested to remove the double quotes, which works, to an extent. After 3 clicks the code stops functioning as expected.

@user3391179's solution doesn't seem to work at all...

Using the `toString` method on `$("#audioWelcome").data("myposition")` will make the "true"/"false" (string) value will work as you would expect them to.

Code:

```
    var myposition = $("#audioWelcome").data("myposition").toString();
    /* changements via onclick */
    if (myposition == "true") {
        $(this).html("afficher le lecteur");
        $('#audioWelcome').data('myposition', false);
    } else if (myposition == "false") {
        $(this).html("cacher le lecteur");
        $('#audioWelcome').data('myposition', true);
    };
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qqK5J/8/

Answer (score 0):

Better yet ditch the == true.  People won't then think you're a VB5 developer

```
if (myposition){}
```

Comment: But then, the condition is always true-ish, even after setting `$('#audioWelcome').data('myposition', 'false');`. You did notice that the value is `'true'` (a string) not `true` (a boolean), yes?

Comment: but if i have others arg than true or false ? i want it like strings, not boolean

Comment: I would avoid using "true" as a string value.  Type in a javascript console:

    var x = "true";
    console.log(x);

You get true   not "true".  It appears to automagically coerce the type for you.  This is why you're having the problem.  Plus using "true" as a string is against what I would consider best practice

Comment: That's just how Chrome decides to print strings. Try it in Firefox instead or trye `var x = "foo"; console.log(x);` (it prints `foo`, without quotes). JavaScript does not coerce the string `"true"` to the boolean value `true`.